# Ubuntu start up shows start up code when it didnt before

Tags: boot, partitioning

I cloned the root partition of my ubuntu install and moved it from /dev/sdc3 to /dev/sdc5. I did this to enable me to increase the partition size because the original was not the last partition. When I booted up again it didn't initially load into the os. I booted from a live os and used auto grub fixer to fix it. This worked but now at every start it takes much longer to load because it shows the start up code when it didn't before. Examples of the code are:
[Code that takes a minute 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRk4L.jpg)
and
"Running /scrips/local-premount ..."
Everything takes about 2 minutes to boot when before it took less than 10 seconds. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I am running LTS 20.04 and I do not know how to change the UUID of the partition. I assumed running the Grub fixer would solve anything like that. Also I cloned using the cp command in the terminal

Comment: You have provided no OS & release details. You also didn't specify if how you cloned the partition, nor if you corrected all UUIDs to reflect change (or those that have changed).  Not having corrected for changed UUIDs will slow boot process down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit `/etc/fstab`.

First, Open `Disks`. Find the partition with `Contents: Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root`. Copy its UUID.

Open `/etc/fstab` from terminal using `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`.
Find the line below `# / was on /dev/sdaXX during installation`. Where `XX` is your partition number. Change the `UUID=` with the one you copied.