# Messed up my swap partition, and now system is taking a very long time to boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, swap

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I wanted to install another distribution in my system, and when installing I used the same partition for the swap as I had in my previous system.

Now every time I boot my system first I get the following error -

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=...
```

The screen stays there for about 3 to 5 minutes and then after some more lines of text it gives me the following prompt-

```
Busybox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) _
```

It goes away and boots normally when I give `exit` as a command but `sudo swapon --show`  gives no output.

I removed the second distribution and tried the following-

1. Formatted the partition I was using as swap as `ext4` and created a `swapfile` using `mkswap` and `swapon` in it by mounting it in `/swap`. And then added its `UUID` to `/etc/fstab` so that it mounts at boot.
2. Directly creating a swap partition there using `sudo mkswap /dev/sdb8`. It created a swap partition of only 10GB, I couldn't find a way to increase it to use the whole partition.
3. Formatted the drive from `gparted` as `linuxswap` and doing `swapon`, and then adding the UUID in `/etc/fstab`

None of the three worked.

My `/etc/fstab` -

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
# auto,rw,users,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show
#  
PARTUUID=32e90fe0-fe01-4e75-8fe5-936dc602c84f  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0
UUID=7a7c38ff-5bb8-473b-b113-f6c61c44490a  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap  none  swap  defaults  0  0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1A5E5F815E5F549B /home/pp/backup_data ntfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=1000,uid=0 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3577A22910382CAD /home/pp/Data ntfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=1000,uid=0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is similar to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278283/ubuntu-start-up-shows-start-up-code-when-it-didnt-before/1278289#1278289).

First, open `Disks`. Find the partition with `Partition type: Linux Swap`. Copy its UUID.

Open `/etc/fstab` from terminal using `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`.
Add the following line:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxxx none            swap    sw              0       0
```

where `xxxxxxxxxx` is the `UUID` you copied. You might need to remove the line

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap  none  swap  defaults  0  0
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did that, in my post, it is the 3rd point that I said I did. Didn't work.

Comment: But I don't see the line in your question. I copied the line corresponding to `swap` from my `etc/fstab`. Your's should look like that. Can you try removing the line `/dev/mapper/cryptswap ...` and adding your `UUID` following my format?

Answer (score -1):

Just open file /etc/crypttab
and change the UUID there to the original Linux-swap(UUID) which you get from the GParted.
Probably this will work,